# How to get innerHTML using CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, casperjs, innerhtml

I want to get attribute of only string in `<em>` tags of HTML page

[image]

I want to get "(868)"

1.

```
casper.then(function() {
     var word = require('utils').dump(this.getElementAttribute(x('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/h4/em'), 'em'));
     console.log(word)
});
```

2.

```
casper.then(function() {
    var word = require('utils').dump(this.getElementAttribute(h4[class="head"], 'em'));
    console.log(word)
});
```

I tried both but it returns "null" How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<em>` is not an element attribute. It's an element itself. `casper.getElementAttribute(selector, attribute)` will correctly retrieve the attribute text of an element, but your want to get the element text.

You can use `casper.fetchText(selector)` for that. Note that `fetchText()` will concatenate the contents of all matched elements into one string. If you don't want that, you either need to make sure that the selector only matches a single element or use other functions such as `casper.getElementInfo(selector).text`.

---

Your second snippet cannot work, because you forgot `"` around the selector and because of the above reason.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used casper.fetchText("h4.head em") and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at documentation FAQ **[Can I access & manipulate DOM elements directly from the CasperJS environment?](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-access-manipulate-dom-elements-directly-from-the-casperjs-environment)**.

In the both of examples that you added in your question you tried to get the `em` element as an attribute of `h4` and that wrong because `em` is a child and not attribute of `h4` tag, so to select `textContent` of an element you can try to use `querySelector` with `evaluate` function like following :

```
casper.then(function() {
    var text = this.evaluate(function(){
        return document.querySelector("h4.head em").textContent;
    });

    var word = require('utils').dump(text);
    console.log(word);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki Thanks a lot!! but it returns string include " " so another answer was better. Thank you for your answer again.